# jsx complied error map within map

Tags: javascript, jsx

```
{!this.state.isLoading && applicants.findIndex(obj => obj.is_new) === 1 &&
    <div>is new</div>
    {applicants.map((obj,index) => {
        if(obj.is_new){
            return this.renderApplicantsList(obj, index)
        }
    })}
}
```

what's wrong with my code above? unexpected token but I can't spot any wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

A JSX element may only contain a single root. The way you are checking for isLoading and is_new is also a bit awkward, I would go for something such as:

```
<div>
  {
    !this.state.isLoading && applicants.findIndex(obj => obj.is_new) === 1 ? (
      <div>
        <div>is new</div>
        {
          applicants.map((obj,index) => {
            if(obj.is_new){
              return this.renderApplicantsList(obj, index)
            }
          })
        }
      </div>
    ) : null
  }
</div>
```

Comment: what's wrong with my checking? We can do like this without ternary operator `{!isLoading && <List />}` right?